# In-App billing Android

Tags: android

My country is not able to link to a merchant account. Which I need for in-app billing and paid apps. But I don't get it why Talking Tom Cat can be selling things, and have an paid app. They are from the same country as myself (Slovenia). And there are many other apps from my country that support in-game billing. But I cannot set up a merchant account.